# Pass bash variable (string) as jq argument to walk JSON object

Tags: json, bash, jq

This is seemingly a *very* basic question. I am new to JSON, so I am prepared for the incoming facepalm.

I have the following JSON file (test-app-1.json):

```
"application.name": "test-app-1",
"environments": {
    "development": [
        "server1"
    ],
    "stage": [
        "server2",
        "server3"
    ],
    "production": [
        "server4",
        "server5"
    ]
}
```

The intent is to use this as a configuration file and reference for input validation.

I am using `bash 3.2` and will be using `jq 1.4` (*not* the latest) to read the JSON.

The problem:
I need to return all values in the specified JSON array based on an argument.

Example: (how the documentation and other resources show that it *should* work)

`APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT="developement"`

`jq --arg appenv "$APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT" '.environments."$env[]"' test-app-1.json`

If executed, this returns `null`. This should return `server1`.

Obviously, if I specify text explicitly matching the JSON arrays under environment, it works just fine: 
`jq 'environments.development[]' test-app-1.json` returns: `server1`.

Limitations: I am stuck to jq 1.4 for this project. I have tried the same actions in 1.5 on a different machine with the same `null` results.

What am I doing wrong here?

jq documentation: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: It's all about quoting. No variables get expanded within single-quotes, i.e. `'stuff'`. Change to `"stuff"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have three issues - two typos and one `jq` filter usage issue:

- set `APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT` to `development` instead of `developement`
- use variable name consistently: if you define `appenv`, use `$appenv`, not `$env`
- address with `.environments[$appenv]`

When fixed, looks like this:

```
$ APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT="development"
$ jq --arg appenv "$APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT" '.environments[$appenv][]' test-app-1.json
"server1"
```

Comment: Apologies for the typos...those were not in the original code I swear :)                Thank you! That worked. Trying to understand how I missed this. Why the `[]` around  `$appenv` in `'.environments.[$appenv][]'` ?

Comment: You can use dot notation `a.b` only for literals; for variables use the brackets, `a[var]`. Just like in JavaScript (JSON's superset).

Comment: Here are the sections of the jq 1.4 docs which describe this: [.foo, .foo.bar](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/3.manual/v1.4/manual.yml#L208-L229) and [.[<string>\], .[2\], .[10:15\]](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/3.manual/v1.4/manual.yml#L251-L295)

Comment: @randomir Yes! sorry for the delay. Thank you so much for your help and the explanation.

Comment: @AustinH, glad it helped. Please also consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so we close this question.